# Visual Studio 2012 Can't compile Dynamic Expressions and Model types

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, dynamic

I have a big problem in Visual Studio 2012. Whenever I start an ASP.Net MVC4 project I get the following errors:

```
Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<Carrousel.Web.ViewModels.LoginViewModel,bool>>' because it is not a delegate type

One or more types required to compile a dynamic expression cannot be found. Are you missing a reference?    d:\Visual Studio\Projects\School\Carrousel v2\Carrousel.Presentation\Views\Account\Login.cshtml

The type arguments for method 'System.Web.Mvc.Html.InputExtensions.TextBoxFor<TModel,TProperty>(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<TModel>, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TModel,TProperty>>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.
```

This happens when there are Dynamic expressions like ViewBag, and Html Form Helpers in a cshtml file.

I have been searching for a while, and the only reasons I could find was if Microsoft.CSharp and/or System.Core is not referenced. However I have both referenced in the project.

This problem only occurs when using Asp.Net Mvc 4, when using Mvc 3 everything works fine. This error occurred on both my Windows 7 and Windows 8 Enterprise versions. I have also tried uninstalling and reinstalling mvc4 through the package manager.

Comment: Is this a duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12782951/c-sharp-dynamic-types-break-when-upgrading-to-visual-studio-2012?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete-and-add your references to the following assemblies:

```
  Microsoft.Scripting.Core.dll  
  Microsoft.CSharp
```

With

```
  CopyToLocal = true
```